# How do I stop my Mac from trying to open new tabs when I make normal clicks?

Tags: keyboard, finder

Yesterday I was using musescore and was playing around with keyboard shortcuts and eventually my mac is now acting weird.

Every time I click on something it opens a new tab (on all my browsers) and I figured out it was NOT a browser issue because when I click on an app on my Dock instead it opens the finder at the application folder which is very bizarre. When I click on icons on top right it doesn't even opens them.

I tried restarting my computer in the hopes that whatever mode I got stuck on would refresh but no luck.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like the Command key is being pressed all the time, maybe it got stuck somehow. What kind of Mac are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For now it seems what solved my problem is completely **shutting down** the mac. I am not sure why restarting didn't work but shutting down and then turning it back on solved it.